# programmatically clicking on input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write javascript function that will automatically click on first input element.

This is the [website](https://adwords.google.com/um/Welcome/Home?a=1&sf=ms&authuser=0#ma).

When I write this in Chrome console I manage to load that edit box with data.

```
var div_cont = document.getElementById('gwt-debug-mcc-account-page-email');
var children=div_cont.getElementsByClassName('umTb-c'); 
children[0].value="heron44@gmx.de";
```

For example:

```
children[0].click();
```

Doesn't work.
Any ideas? Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: google has a lot of code running in background that may mess up your results. Also, why would you click on an input programmatically if you can easily set its contents?

Comment: what kind of input is it? a button?

Comment: @Jonasw because it gives me the result only when i click it and then click something else(i managed to set its content right away). I use SendMouseEventClick, that was the onlu thing that worked after couple of hours trying, thanks anyways

Comment: @MotassemMK it is edit text input, just like this for writing a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to **focus** the `input`, rather than **click** it.

If that's the case, you could just use

```
children[0].focus();
```

at the console.

The thing is you won't focus the `input` that way, because when you call that command, the Chrome Console will be focused, not the browser viewport.

All in all, what I suggest is to **run the following snippet at the console, then go back to the page** (click the background, anything).

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('focusing now!');
    children[0].focus();
}, 3000)
```

This code focus the `children[0]` input after 3s.

Answer (score -1):

If you have jquery, which your tag suggests you do, you can trigger a click event with the $(...).trigger('click') method (see http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(children[0]).trigger('click')
```